# C++ beginner: Returning a single value. Issue: my amount is rounding and I don't want it to

Tags: c++

I'm working on an exercise to return a single value. It seems to work ok except that it returns a rounded value and not the exact value to two decimal places. How do I force it to return the exact value?

Edit: I changed the following lines:

```
 total = a * 1 + b * 5 + c * 10 + d * 25;
 cout << "\nThe total number of dollars is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) 
<< dollar/100 << endl;
```

Is this acceptable or a clumsy workaround?

My code:

```
int totAmt(double, double, double, double);

int main()
 {
double pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters, dollar;

cout << "\nEnter the number of pennies: ";
cin  >> pennies;
cout << "\nEnter the number of nickels: ";
cin  >> nickels;
cout << "\nEnter the number of dimes: ";
cin  >> dimes;
cout << "\nEnter the number of quarters: ";
cin  >> quarters;

dollar = totAmt(pennies, nickels, dimes, quarters);

cout << "\nThe total number of dollars is $" << fixed << setprecision(2) 
     << dollar << endl;

return 0;
}

int totAmt(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
double total;
total = a * .01 + b * .05 + c * .1 + d * .25;

return total;
}
```

Comment: Please Please Please do not store currency in floating point numbers. Get rounding errors and people get fickle over their cash. That includes non-humans - accountants!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Return a double. Conversion from double to int does the rounding or more precisely it is truncating.

```
double totAmt(double a, double b, double c, double d)
{
    double total;
    total = a * .01 + b * .05 + c * .1 + d * .25;

    return total;
}
```

As stated by Ed Heal in the comments, you should however use `int` to store dollars amount(in cents or according to the smallest of your currency) but multiply all amount by 100 to do accurate calculations. Float and double are not totally precise because of their binary representation.

**EDIT**

According to your new calculation, to accurately display the amount, you could use:

```
total = a * 1 + b * 5 + c * 10 + d * 25;
cout << "\nThe total number of dollars is $" << total/100 << "." << total%100 << endl;
```

Comment: If you have any sense you use int to store cents. Now that is a play on words

Comment: That worked. Thank you! I thought I had tried that earlier but nope.

Comment: @Monica - Just store currency as integers

Comment: @EdHeal Yeah cents, haha.

Comment: @EricFortin - You get a +1 for finding my pun funny

Answer (score 0):

the function totAmt(double, double, double, double) is returning an int, declare as a double and it will run just fine